# Is there a way to use Python 3.5 on Cygwin?

Tags: python, cygwin

Python 2.7 works fine but I would like to use 3.5, is there a way to do this?

When installing packages for Cygwin, the "latest" version of Python was 2.7, so if I am answering my own question here please let me know.

Comment: As to when Python 3.5 will be upgraded, see this [blog post](http://cygwin.1069669.n5.nabble.com/Python-3-5-2-td130371.html) as of October 2016. `Whenever I have the time to deal with the upgrade of not only python3 
but everything which uses it.`

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Consider installing the `python3` package.

http://cygwin.com/packages/x86_64/python3

Current version is 3.4.3

Comment: Does anybody know if 3.5 will be ported soon?

Comment: Yeah, it's been almost half a year since 3.5.0

Comment: -1 for not answering the question.  Title clearly asks "Python 3.5" and you ignore it and provide advice for installing 3.4.3.

Comment: "No" appears to be the correct simple answer to the question (to date)... unless one is willing to do the porting work themselves (which can safely be assumed to not be part of the ask). While this answer does not explicitly say "no" (because it shouldn't due to the porting possibility), it pretty clearly implies "no" to me by stating the latest supported version to date. Thus, I don't understand the -2 dismissal of this answer. It succeeds at communicating what was wanted to be known even though it wasn't the answer that was perhaps hoped for.

Answer (score 0):

According to Cygwin's [package list](https://cygwin.com/packages/package_list.html), Python 3.5 was made available via the [installer](https://www.cygwin.com/) in February 2019. The "python35" package and/or its affiliates (e.g. python35-devel) should be selected when [running the installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17825023/installing-additional-packages-for-cygwin).