# "Nothing to Install/Update" in Cygwin when Using Setup to Install Packages

Tags: windows, cygwin, installation

I'm trying to install new packages in cygwin, but when I get to the package list it's empty with the message "Nothing to Install/Update".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select **Full** in the **View** drop-down list in the top left of the package list view.

[image: Selecting **Full** in the **View** drop-down list in the Cygwin Setup package list view.]

The package list view defaults to **Pending** when running the setup again after Cygwin is already installed.

---

This Q&A is posted as a quick answer for anyone else that didn't see the **View** drop-down option right away.

Comment: this doesn't work for me. still not showing any packages.

Comment: do note that it's a 32-bit install

Comment: The only thing I can think of is a problem with your internet, maybe the firewall? Looks like there's a workaround you can use though: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28857280/4036475